# How to use delegates

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I am currently using this code to move clamps:

```
Public Class ClampSet
    Public Sub New(ByVal gripL As Single, ByVal gripR As Single, ByVal passAxis As Integer)
        GripDistanceRight.DimMillimeters = gripL
        GripDistanceLeft.DimMillimeters = gripR
        Axis = passAxis
    End Sub

    Public GripDistanceRight As clsDimension = New clsDimension()
    Public GripDistanceLeft As clsDimension = New clsDimension()
    Public Axis As Integer

    Public Sub moveClampIn()
        If (Axis = 1) Then
            digiouts.MoveLeftClampIn()
        ElseIf Axis = 2 Then
            digiouts.MoveMiddleClampIn()
        ElseIf Axis = 3 Then
            digiouts.MoveRightClampIn()
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub moveClampOut()
        If (Axis = 1) Then
            digiouts.MoveLeftClampOut()
        ElseIf Axis = 2 Then
            digiouts.MoveMiddleClampOut()
        ElseIf Axis = 3 Then
            digiouts.MoveRightClampOut()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am trying to learn more about OO programming and I am having trouble understanding Delegates.

I think I could pass a delegate as a parameter into a move() function so that this class could provide me with the option of specifying which method(i.e. MoveLeftClampOut()) I really want to use when I initialize the ClampSet object.

And I think this would be a better solution as I don't know how many different clampMove methods I will have in the future I will have in the future and would like to make my Code more flexible.

If I can use delegates to change which method is executed by a ClampSet Object on move(), What should my code look like to accomplish that?

P.S. I have to use the methods that are provided to me by someone elses class. (MoveLeftClampIn(), MoveLeftClampOut(), etc..)

Comment: Read up on the Magic Number anti-pattern while you're getting good at OO, bad habit to start doing. :)

Comment: @Cortright Exactly why I'm asking the question :) I know its bad and I want to do better

Comment: The problem is that you *think* you need delegates in this code.  You don't, there's absolutely no use for them.  Keep writing code and you'll find an obvious need for them.  Like some day you'll think it's useful to raise an event.

Comment: I am also curious why you think you need delegates, as @HansPassant is.  What is your understanding of what a delegate is?  They are not that complex, but the concept can be hard to grasp until you start using them.

Comment: @HansPassant Let's see if I have at least the basic understanding of Delegates.. In the code above, I would like to have each ClampSet object execute a different function (i.e. MoveLeftClampIn()) so If i could pass that method to the ClampSet instance at Initialization, I could have as many different clampmove functions as I want without changing the Clampset class. What am I missing in this description?

Comment: ClampSet is a noun.  A delegate is a verb.  Having a ClampSet being able to do only one Move ought to be a problem.  Add a Move() method with a delegate argument and things start to make more sense.

Comment: @HansPassant that might be what I am looking for. could you show me an example of how I would do that in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is better for you, to use the select statement in your case. A delegate is not necessary. For example: you can use a delegate to call a method that is currently in use by another thread for safe coding.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Currently coding in c#, so it got me confused. Updated the answer.